# get Admin controller URL in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, admin-controller, urlbuilder

Here is my Directory structure of controller file in Magento 2 - 
app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Controller/Adminhtml/Blacklist/Index.php

In Index.php i write the below code -

```
namespace Mynamespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\ModuleDirectoryname;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $helper;
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \VT\Blacklist\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->viewHelper = $viewHelper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "hello"; die;
    }
}
```

I am using this Inject - \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $urlBuilder, in my another __construct function and printing url through -

```
echo $url = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('namespace_modulename/adminhtml/moduledirectoryname/index');
```

but once i m running above printed url its redirecting to Dashboard not printing 'hello' ;

Can you plz let me know What I m missing here ?

Comment: How you browse this controller?

Comment: No need to use adminhtml in your path. Should be 'admin_route_frontName/moduledirectoryname/index'. admin_route_frontName - is from your etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because your URL is not properly generated.

Let's take the following example:

```
getUrl('adminRouteFrontName/controllerFolder/actionClass')
```

Here is how an URL should be generated and here is how you must replace the values:

- **adminRouteFrontName** : it is the value declared in your `adminhtml/routes.xml` so I'm not sure what you put there in your case
- **controllerFolder** : name of the controller folder under `Controller/Adminhtml` so in your case it's ModuleDirectoryname
- **actionClass** : name of your action class under the controller folder for example with `Index.php` it would be `index`, for `Grid.php` it would be `grid` and so in your case it is `index`

So if you got those three things right, I'm pretty sure you should try removing the `adminhtml` from your parameter.

Comment: here 'namespace_modulename' is  adminRouteFrontName and "adminhtml/moduledirectoryname/" is folder structure and "Index" is action class .

Comment: But If I create a directory in 'Adminhtml' directory and then difining the action class, So, Is it wrong way ?

Comment: @Atul no it's good but `controllerFolder` must be the name of the folder under `Controller/Adminhtml` so you need to remove `adminhtml` from your URL

Comment: i tried its works but giving this issue -  "

Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Blacklist\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /home/mage2demo/public_html/mage21new/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /home/mage2demo/public_html/mage21new/app/code/Namespace\Modulename/Controller/Adminhtml/Blacklist/index.php on line 13

 "

Comment: I also did upgrade n compilation but its coming after that also...

Comment: @Atul it seems like you changed the constructor of your controller. Please post the updated code as the code in your question looks OK.

Comment: Its same nothing changed -

Comment: @Atul well the error says that you tried to inject the ObjectManager and the code in your question does not show that. Try to remove `var/generation`

Comment: I tried by removing "var/generation"  then again run upgrade n compile  But same result.

Comment: @Atul you definitely have a problem with your controller. Feel free to open a new question as your original question has now been fixed

Comment: Hey @RaphaelatDigitalPianism : what if frontend and adminhtml routes name are same?

Comment: I spent 4 hours because I didn't read the last line of your response. WE DON'T NEED to add `adminhtml` as parameter in getUrl for admin controllers. Thanks for that.